# How to create package to install font in mac OS

Tags: font-book, pkg

I just created a .pkg using the following command:

```
pkgbuild --identifier com.vinivia.xxxxxx --version 1.0 --component /Users/xxxxxx/ViniviaPoppins-AllinOne/ViniviaPoppins-AllinOne.ttc --install-location ~/Library/Fonts --sign "MySign" /Users/xxxxxx/ViniviaPoppins/ViniviaPoppins.pkg
```

However, when I try to install it, the font gets copied to `~/Library/Fonts` but doesn't show up in Font Book. Does anyone have any ideas on how to create a .pkg and install it in Font Book?

Comment: If you drop it into `~/Library/Fonts` yourself, does it appear?

Comment: @MarcWilson Yes, it also appears when I use the following command :
find /Users/xxxxxx/ViniviaPoppins-AllinOne/ -type f -name "*.ttc" -exec cp -n {} ~/Library/Fonts \;

Comment: I presume it's a caching issue. Does it show up after a restart? What happens if you do `atsutil fonts -list` or `-verify` ??

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I tried to restart by calling the commands - 'atsutil server -shutdown' & 'atsutil server -ping' but it led to nothing.
After calling the command 'atsutil fonts -list' I also did not see my font in the list

Comment: Why are you building a package to install fonts? You can just double-click or right click/install.

Comment: I meant an actual OS restart, not just the font server. Come to think of it, I have created a pkg to install fonts fairly recently, and it worked fine. Check the file attributes on the font itself?